# ListViewGroups vanish when used in WinForms ToolStripControlHost

Tags: vb.net, winforms, listview, toolstripcontrolhost

Windows 10, VS 2019 Community, VB.Net...

I'm wanting to use a listview control as a custom menu. Created a usercontrol, added a listview and populated it with groups and items in each group. I then added it to a ToolStripControlHost, and this was in turn added to a ContextMenuStrip which serves as the dropdown for a menu item on my form. Works fine except that the groups don't show up. The listview items are there but no groups. What might cause this? This image:

[image: 1]

shows the usercontrol in the designer and also at runtime. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like the `View` of the `ListView` has somehow been changed from `SmallIcon` to `List`. That would also account for the fact that the item order is different.

Comment: Can you show us the relevant code? I just tried a quick test and I don't see any items or groups at all, so I must have done something different to you. I don't want to spend any more time on it without knowing exactly what you're doing so I can use that as a starting point.

Comment: The ListView groups and items are added in the designer.

Comment: @#jmcilhinney

The ListView groups and items are added in the designer. The ListView is in a UserControl called CustomMenu. The ListView's View property is set to Details with one column. 
 
In main window the controlhost is created...
    Dim WithEvents tch As New ToolStripControlHost(New CustomMenu)

I added a ContextMenuStrip called cntx to the main form. In the Load event the   ToolStripControlHost is added to it:
            cntx.Width = tch.Width + 2
            cntx.Height = tch.Height + 5
            cntx.Items.Add(tch)
            cntx.Padding = New Padding(0, 0, 0, 0)

Comment: As you can see, code is barely readable in a comment, especially when not formatted. No one should have to read the comments to fully understand the question anyway. If there is relevant information missing from the question, add it to the question.